# Object import failed: Bad Request (400) received - {'playbook': ['Playbook not found for project.']}. by awxkit

Tags: ansible, ansible-template, ansible-awx

I try to backup and restore AWX to another instance.
They have the same environment and the same version ansible and AWX.
I export data:

`awx export > all.json`

and import on another instance.

`awx import < all.json`

And I got this

`Object import failed: Bad Request (400) received - {'playbook': ['Playbook not found for project.']}.`

I had tried old tool `tower-cli` Also got this:

```
Failed to create job_template OperationVue : The Tower server claims it was sent a bad request.

POST http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v2/job_templates/
Params: None
Data: {"name": "OperationVue", "inventory": 2, "project": 8, "playbook": "developUpdateVersion.yml", "extra_vars": "{\"host\": \"api\"}", "job_tags": "OperationVue", "ask_job_type_on_launch": true, "diff_mode": true, "job_type": "run"}

Response: {"playbook":["Playbook not found for project."]}

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
    ok=0    changed=0    warnings=0    failed=3
```

Can't import my job_templates. But other items are successful : Credentials, Projects, Inventories, Organizations.

Have anyone like this?

Or Please tell me how to backup and restore AWX. Thank you.

Comment: Awx does not export credentials contents (i.e actual password, ssh private key content....). This is a known limitation^w security feature. Once credentials and projects are imported, you need to 1) recreate the credentials contents 2) update the projects - before you import the job templates si that the playbooks can be found. Bulk import in one go will not work.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because your credentials are created with blank passwords and the project providing the playbook failed to sync with SCC. That was my issue anyway...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).